# How to use Poisson Lambda

Tags: poisson-distribution

I am writing a piece of software that requires Poisson distribution with an average, or lambda, of 5 events per seconds.

I am passing the lambda in a loop that "sleeps" a number of milliseconds to generate those events at random intervals, but I am unclear of whether I need to pass to the Poisson function the value of 5, or the value of 200, which is 1000 / 5, where 1000 is the number of milliseconds in a second.

Which value should I pass as `lambda` to the Poisson function?

This is the code of the function:

```
static double poissonRandomNumber(int lambda) {
    double L = Math.exp(-lambda);
    int k = 0;
    double p = 1;
    do {
        k = k + 1;
        double u = Math.random();
        p = p * u;
    } while (p > L);
    return k - 1;
}
```

Comment: You should definitely pass 5 to the Poisson generator. But why not sample the wait times directly as exponential random variables? Either way, the lambda should always be the number of events within one time unit (5 Hz or 0.005 kHz or 0.005 events per millesecond). https://nicolewhite.github.io/2015/05/23/understanding-waiting-times.html

Answer (score 0):

The *counts* in a fixed interval of time is Poisson, but the time interval between them is continuous; it could not be Poisson.

If you want to sleep for the time between events in a Poisson process, you need to use an *exponential* wait time.

See, for example, the last paragraph of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process) subsection, or the first sentence of [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Memoryless_property).